# Injecting instance dependent on HttpServletRequest

Tags: dependency-injection, jersey, guice

I'm currently setting up a rather big existing project for dependency-injection with guice and would need to access the request scoped HttpServletRequest instance injected into the rest-endpoint via @Context. The reason I need the HttpServletRequest instance it to create an object RequestContext needed for multiple of the backend services.

I've tried to add a guice Provider class:

```
public class JerseyRequestCtxProvider implements Provider<IRequestContext> {
    private final HttpServletRequest request;

    @Inject
    public JerseyRequestCtxProvider(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public IRequestContext get() {
        return new RequestContext(request);
    }
}
```

and finally add it to the guice module as so:

```
bind(IRequestCtx.class).toProvider(JerseyRequestCtxProvider.class);
```

I've also tried to have the HttpServletRequest as a Provider itself and added the guice servlet filter, but no luck there.

Is it even possible to get access to the HttpServletRequest in guice, if the endpoints are managed by jersey?

Comment: Are you using the ServletModule for guice?

Comment: @pandaadb: You are right, didn't use the ServletModule. Stupid me :-(